# How can I learn about Distributed Software Systems as efficiently as possible?

Tags: cloud-computing, grid-computing

I'm trying to learn cloud-computing, especially the idea of distributed operations (Grid Computing?) for a project I'm working on.  We'll need to perform distributed fault-tolerant operations over a very large data set, which we will also be responsible for storing and maintaining in an optimized way.

If I'm trying to learn from books or white-papers, what types of things should I look out for and focus on to help me gain this knowledge as efficiently and effectively as possible?

Comment: Programmers.SE is [not a discussion board](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/): indiscriminate lists like this diminish the usefulness of this site for people trying to get answers to specific questions. If you have a specific problem you need help with, feel free to ask about that.

Comment: @Mark Trapp Would not "I'm trying to find a good base of literature from which to learn distributed operations" qualify as a specific problem?  I've seen many other "recommended book list" questions....

Comment: present a specific problem you need help with: "I'm trying to do X, what can I do?" or "I'm trying to get help with X specific situation, would Y book be useful for this?" or "How would I go about selecting a book for X?" are all on-topic questions. Asking for book recommendations doesn't help us help you get to a solution: answerers can only guess what book is going to be useful to you. Check out [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more information.

Comment: @Mark Trapp so something like the recent edit?

Comment: you're still just asking for a list of book recommendations. The point of Stack Exchange is to provide direct answers, not to crowd-source reading lists: we can help you with any questions you have regarding Distributed Software Systems directly. I've edited your question to that effect and get it away from being just a book recommendation question.

Answer (score 2):

This may be noteworthy, I hesitate to say it's a place to start though and should definitely be accompanied by material that isn't so whitepaper-ey. It's very dry.
http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/labs.google.com/en//papers/bigtable-osdi06.pdf

Comment: It also needs mentioning that the whitepaper is from 2006, it is *not* recent.

Comment: Not recent, but informative nonetheless.  Good find.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this book: 
[Beautiful Architecture: Leading Thinkers Reveal the Hidden Beauty in Software Design](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517984)

It probably isn't completely related to the concepts that you have listed (it is more higher level).  I still believe that there are some related examples and presented in an approachable manner.